# is it possible to call a web service when i delete the app from my iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview, appdelegate

I want to send a web service,when i delete my app (pressing OK button on alert 
    message) from iphone.
    is any possibilities to handle like that situation? if we do like that
    app store will accept that app.

**Note:
I know we can't control the apple alert messages.but is any other possibilities**

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. No event is triggered when an app is deleted. When an app is deleted, the app is not running so there is no way it can do any processing of any kind.

Comment: Okay, but apple also showing one alert.when i press ok button the app is deleting mease ios performing some action on that event. i want that control.

Comment: @srinadh not possible.. It is OS level control, and not public.

Comment: @srinadh You can't get control, at least with public APIs for apps in the App  Store. I have no idea if this is possible with private APIs or a jailbreak. If your app is for the App Store, it can't be done.

Comment: ok how to call web service before deleting the app from my iphone. by using the appdelegate methods.

Comment: @srinadh You can't. How many different ways must I give you the same answer. An app is not given any notice that it is being deleted. There is no app delegate method for this. You can't do what you are asking for. I'm sorry but that is the simple truth.

Comment: @rmaddy, Thank you for your valuable suggestion